# Add validation when specific radio button is selected

Tags: jquery

I have 3 radio buttons, and I want to throw validation if first radio button is selected_

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="prov" value="P">
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="user" value="U">
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="suc" value="S">

<select id="lst1"></select>
<select id="lst2"></select>
 <a href="javascript:;" id="event_add" class="btn green"> button </a>
```

If I debbug `$('input:radio[name="editList"]').val()` it always come "P"  why it happens?

There is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ad7A/701/) of problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret with radio buttons is that you have to use the `:checked` pseudo-selector in conjunction with `val()`. You're currently always returning `P` because that is the **first** option for the group of radio buttons (and therefor the **default**). You need to check for change by using `:checked`, like you would for a checkbox.

In order to find the value of the radio button that's currently selected, you're looking for:

```
$('input:radio[name="editList"]:checked').val()
```

You also need to actually pass the condition where you check against `P` into the click of the button itself:

```
$('#event_add').click(function() {
  if ($('input:radio[name="editList"]:checked').val() === "P") {
    if ($('#lst2').val() === '') {
      alert('You need to select something into lst2.');
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a minimalist example:

```js
$('#event_add').click(function() {
  console.log($('input:radio[name="editList"]:checked').val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="prov" value="P">
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="user" value="U">
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="suc" value="S">
<a href="javascript:;" id="event_add" class="btn green"> button </a>
```

I've also created an updated fiddle demonstrating your code working **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/d3f0g8t4/)**.

Hope this helps! :)